# 5250 Web Browser Emulation with Kerberos

Tags: ibm-midrange, kerberos

We have an AS/400 iSeries V7 R1

Currently running "IBM i Access for Windows" on our users PC's

We have a need for multiple users on our network to access *VIA a Web Browser* their "green screens", hosted on the iSeries also on our network.

We also have a requirement that once logged into their Windows domain account, they need not type in their user credentials to the web emulation... which is currently how the Windows emulator works (with Kerberos)

Does the "iSeries Access for Web" allow this?

And, how do I get started on my local computer, actually experimenting with the browser interface?  I see no where to download anything from [IBM's site documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzamm/rzammportletsref5250.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser interface uses a browser.  There isn't anything to download.  The link references the 5250 portlet, which you would put on a page served by your WebSphere Application Server.  The [WebSphere Portal InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/pvc/wp/502/smbi/en/InfoCenter/index.html) will help you understand how to set the authentication up.  Especially see Securing your portal > Security concepts > Authentication.  Here is the home page for [IBM i Access for Web](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/web.html).  In particuklar, check out the [documentation link](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/web_resources.html) at the bottom.

If you are V5R4, be advised that support is about to elapse.

Comment: Thanks Buck.  Though 5% of my questions are iSeries related, you've answered a number of my questions in the past too!!

Comment: After re-reading my answer, I see I wasn't really clear when it comes to 'how do I get started?'  With the portal, it's all on the server side; there's nothing to do on the desktop.